# How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, release-management

What are the different ways I can use to upgrade Ubuntu from one release to another?

Comment: Related: [Upgrade from a previous version of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade) on the Ubuntu website.

Comment: `sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade -y`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

`sudo shutdown -r now`

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 321):

### Summary

This answer summarizes the recommended [community upgrade process](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades).

You should always read the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes) for any potential issues that may affect your upgrade.

### Backup

Before you start any upgrade process – ask yourself this question:

*Can I afford to lose any/all my data such as documents and files?*

If the answer is no - then **[backup your installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)**.

Upgrading Ubuntu works 99 times out of 100 – a backup will save you lots of frustration later if things do go wrong.

[Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

### Graphics

If you have installed proprietary drivers from the *Additional Drivers* or *Hardware Drivers* window then these should be automatically upgraded with the Nvidia/ATI binary driver appropriate for 12.04/14.04

If you have downloaded and installed proprietary drivers manually directly from the manufacturers website then the recommendation is to remove these drivers first and revert to the open-source drivers before upgrading.  Potentially what can happen is that a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file will remain after the upgrade and subsequently on first reboot, you will boot into a 'black screen'.

These questions describe the removal process:

1. [How do I remove ATI/AMD Drivers downloaded from their site?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88573/how-do-i-remove-ati-amd-drivers-downloaded-from-their-site)
2. [Remove nVidia driver and go back to Nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau)

### PPAs

During the upgrade, any PPA sources you may have added will be automatically disabled.  Generally, PPAs do not affect the upgrade process.

There are a couple of specific PPAs that could cause issues - *x-swat* and *xorg-edgers*.  These [PPAs should be removed](https://askubuntu.com/a/91660/3940) via `ppa-purge` before upgrading

1. [ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates)
2. [xorg-edgers/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Exorg-edgers/+archive/ppa)

### How to Upgrade

Your 13.10 upgrade program will alert you of the new release and offer an upgrade. If this does not happen then see the trouble-shooting section below.

Please see the trouble-shooting section for the special case for LTS users between 12.04/14.04 and the release 12.04.1/14.04.1

The official [ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com) page has information:

- For [desktop and server editions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/upgrade).

Immediately after a Ubuntu release, the download servers are extremely busy.  Thus, if you can, we suggest to wait a few days if you want to upgrade.

Alternatively, download using a bittorrent client such as Transmission, the official desktop ISO torrent.

### Upgrade over the Network

You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

1. Launch the update manager.
2. Click the Check button to check for new updates.
3. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
4. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.

For 10.04LTS/12.04LTS users you need to check the "Release upgrade - Show new distribution releases" drop-down to make sure "Long term support releases only" is selected, and change it if otherwise. See the Trouble-shooting section below for more details.  Please see the trouble-shooting section for the special case for LTS users between 12.04/14.04 and the release 12.04.1/14.04.1

[image: update-manager-upgrade]

1. Click Upgrade.

Follow the on-screen instructions.

See Also:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades for more information on some alternate methods of upgrading for certain cases.

### Upgrading by using the CD or USB image

If you are using 10.04 LTS/12.04 LTS or 11.10/13.10 and you either insert the live CD or boot from the live CD to start installing it will give a option of upgrading to 12.04/14.04. It will automatically detect installed applications and install the updated version of your applications also.

If you download an ISO, the recommendation is to perform a [md5sum check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31888/how-to-verify-that-the-iso-i-downloaded-is-bootable-before-i-burn-it) to ensure both the ISO downloaded and the burned CD are valid.

- **Upgrade from 10.04 LTS/12.04 LTS** (here shown with dual boot):

NOTE: Upgrades from 10.04 to 12.04 / Upgrades from 12.04 to 14.04 are not activated yet, see this question for more detail:

- [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-a-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts)
- **Upgrade from 11.10/13.10**
  [image]

### Upgrading using the command line (eg Ubuntu Server):

11.10/13.10 and later

- Run `do-release-upgrade` in a terminal

10.04/12.04

- edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=lts`
- Run `do-release-upgrade` in a terminal

### Troubleshooting

If your 10.04/12.04 or 11.10/13.10 update-manager does not prompt you to upgrade, then check your [software sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115913/disable-ubuntu-update-managers-new-version-warning) to see if it is set to "Never".  If it is then change the value to "Long Term Support Releases Only" (10.04 LTS/12.04 LTS) / "For any new version" (11.10/13.01):

[image]
<sup>for 10.04 LTS/12.04 LTS</sup>

[image]
<sup>for 11.10/13.10</sup>

According to Ubuntu Engineering Foundations team manager Steve Langasek:

> Upgrades between LTS releases are not enabled by default until the first point release,  It is recommended that most LTS users wait until then before upgrading.

If you choose to upgrade before then, you can pass the -d option to the upgrade tool, running `do-release-upgrade -d` or `update-manager -d`, to upgrade from vanilla 10.04/12.04 to 12.04/14.04.

See this Q&A for further details:

[Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-a-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts)

### If you are using an [End of life version of Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29)

You might need to make changes to `/etc/apt/sources.list` to refer to the *old-releases* server of Ubuntu. Follow the answers given in this question to make necessary modifications and then upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu:

- [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 93):

Here is my advice as a tutorial-like answer, based on my experience upgrading.

This procedure was tested by me, and it worked as it should. Hopefully this will help others to upgrade without problems.

**This is not an official guide.**

## Friendly advice

There is no reason to rush. There is no reason to upgrade from day one. The new Ubuntu version is not going away. It will still be there the next week and the next month... Leave the servers to calm down. It will be very frustrating and painful if the server goes down during the upgrade.

## Starting off

First of all we have to check if the new version is available. 
Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and give this command:

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

This command will check if the new version is available from the servers and will return the result. If you find this command is not available, you need to install the `update-manager-core` package. If your distro is no longer supported you will need to search for old mirrors for a copy of this package before you can use this upgrade method.

If the version is available we can proceed.

**If the version is not available** then check one more thing. Open this file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

and see if **Prompt is equal to normal** `Prompt=normal`. If it is not, then change it;  after you have saved the file, run the commands below in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update 
do-release-upgrade -c
```

## Before Upgrade

### Remove all the external PPAs

You have to remove all the PPAs you have added in the past. Some of them may not work, some of them may be unsupported or even deprecated in the new version.

Open the Ubuntu **Software Center and click Edit > Software sources > Other Software** and then click and remove all the PPAs one by one.

#### Be careful

Some PPAs, such as [Ubuntu X-team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates), [“xorg crack pushers” team](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) or [“GNOME3 Team” team](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3), upgrade some essential packages of the system.

You have to remove these PPAs using another method: install **ppa-purge**. This script will allow you to **downgrade** all the essential packages to the original (official) Ubuntu version. Execute the commands below in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa-name
```

Replace `ppa-name` with the actual name of the repository. After the purge you can run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update the sources.

### Housekeeping

It is a good idea to do a little housekeeping before an upgrade to a new version. Open a terminal and execute the commands below, in order:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print $2 }')
```

The first line will remove/fix any residual/broken packages if any. The clean command removes all old .deb files from the apt cache (/var/cache/apt/archives) - this isn't strictly necessary, but it's a very good idea if you're at all low on disk space.

`sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print $2 }')` removes package configurations left over from packages that have been [removed (but not purged)](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/dpkg-what-does-a-status-of-%27rc%27-mean-355593/).

### Search for Bugs

The most common and usual problem is graphics card driver issues. Search for bugs before upgrading. Go to the [Launchpad page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/), use the search box to find your graphics card model (even better, the id) and browse the bugs. If you find some, consider waiting to upgrade until later, when the bug(s) have been fixed. If the bug is specific to the **additional driver (restricted)** then **remove the driver** before upgrading.

### Custom Kernel (Unofficial)

If you have a custom kernel, either from compile or from a .deb package (e.g. mainline), then it is a good idea to boot from the official Ubuntu kernel when upgrading, else the upgrade may fail.

## Release Upgrade

### From terminal

Most users upgrade from the Update-manager. It is not that I don't trust it, but I trust the terminal more.

**Close all the applications** and open only a terminal (full-screen).
Give this command and the upgrade will begin:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

#### During upgrade

- Do not open any applications, leave this until after the reboot.
- Do not navigate into the Desktop environment, you will have the time to do
  this later. Get a cup of coffee, relax and wait, be patient until the
  upgrade finishes.
- If you have to intervene during the upgrade (from within the terminal), you can do
  so with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For example, if you have two
  Display Managers (e.g LightDM and GDM), the upgrade will ask you which you want to use; press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the one you want is highlighted, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

### Enjoy!

> Feel free to edit this answer and make it more understandable
>   (language correction) or/and improve it (additions).

Comment: I do not think you need to manually remove PPAs, do-release-upgrade will do that for you.

Comment: @JorgeCastro sometimes it doesn't or things getting confused.It is not difficult to remove them manually and it is more safe. Either way this is only my how to. :-)

Comment: @Aditya: The housekeeping section will remove/fix any residual/broken packages if any. `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` will remove any residual packages so does `sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print $2 }')` but in effective way if previous fails to do. Although I think `sudo apt-get clean all` is not needed as it will remove *.deb packages (say setup packages) which keep stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives` when you install any new package from repository. I hope your double is clear now. :)

Answer (score 24):

Try with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 21):

My method, based on half a decade's experience of painful ubuntu upgrades, is different. I'm not trolling, just sharing the methods I use.

Of course you can't afford to lose all your **data**, so yes, **back it up**. But I start from an earlier question: can you afford to not be able to **access** your data because everything's broken? If not, then this method might be for you. You need a little free disk space.

I keep 2 operating system primary partitions (and a separate one for data, swap...). So, for example, I have Natty at `/dev/sda1`, and have been running Precise Beta in `/dev/sda2`.

Then I choose an option: upgrade or clean install. As Linux Mint point out, an upgrade never feels like a clean install, but sometimes you want that.

**For a clean install** you just plug in your new USB stick and tell it to install in `/dev/sda2`, pointing `/home` to your existing home partition.

**To do an upgrade** I image `sda2` from `sda1`. There are many ways to do this, `fsarchiver` is good, or plain ol' cp or tar will do the trick. Once I've made identical copies of all files in the spare partition, I mount it and edit `/etc/fstab` to update the UUIDs for the new partition or it will get confused. Then I run grub-update and next time I reboot grub offers me 2 choices. I check that I can boot either. Then do your upgrade as above.

Further warning: new desktop versions tend to mangle old desktop config files. So you can end up with the old and new systems being broken. If you have the disk space, `cp -ar /home/{youruser,newname}` and point the new user's HOME to this new path in `/etc/passwd`.

Having 2 OS partitions gives me a fallback; If something in the new system (might be a driver, a bug, a missing app...) is affecting productivity, I can at least go back to where I was. **It's obviously not for the feint-hearted or noob.**

Comment: This is my method, too, although I also make a new copy of my home partition, because as you said, changes made to user config files in the new OS could cause problems if you have to fall back. My big stuff, like data (music, photos, documents) and Wine installations are on a separate drive, and get inserted into my new home directory via a few symlinks.

Comment: @glibdud: symlinks to music, photos, documents: that is *the* most sane and safe layout. For me, it is **The One True Layout**. $HOME is full of os-(and version-)dependent config files, re-using them in a clean install will not be a clean install after all. $HOME should be considered part of your OS install. So move "big stuff" away, and let a clean install purge config and settings, then set symlinks back.

Comment: I'm trying to use this method and running into some issues. I could use some assistance. I started a new thread at http://askubuntu.com/questions/607008/problem-cloning-root-and-home-before-doing-an-upgrade-from-trusty-to-utopic

Comment: In the `cp` command, the `-a` switch works as `-dR --preserve=all`, and `-R` works the same as `-r`, so it's sufficient to command `cp -a ...`.

Comment: when you say "pointing `/home` to your existing home partition, do you mean during installation, under "Something Else (in the installer)," mounting this existing home partition to `/home` in the new installation, and of course mounting the disk that your installing the new OS on to `/`?  That won't immediately overwrite everything that's on your current home partition? (technically asking anyone here)

Comment: @Life5ign yes, that is what I meant. As long as it's not scheduled to FORMAT /home then it should be fine. That said, backup backup backup is safest way!

Answer (score 15):

The official ubuntu.com page has information:

- For [desktop and server editions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/upgrade).

You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

1. Launch the software center.
2. Go to Edit -> Software Sources
3. Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application:

   [image: software-sources]
4. Change the Release Update drop down to "Normal Releases" and close the application
5. Launch the update manager.
6. Click the Check button to check for new updates.
7. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
8. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.

   [image: update-manager-upgrade]
9. Click Upgrade.

Follow the on-screen instructions.

See Also:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades for more information on some alternate methods of upgrading for certain cases.

From the [technical overview](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/TechnicalOverview):

> To upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 on a desktop system, press Alt+F2 and type in `update-manager` (without the quotes) into the command box. Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '11.10' is available. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.
>
> To upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 on a server system: install the `update-manager-core` package if it is not already installed; launch the upgrade tool with the command `sudo do-release-upgrade` and follow the on-screen instructions. Note that the server upgrade is now more robust and will utilize GNU screen and automatically re-attach in case of e.g. dropped connection problems.

### Upgrading by using the CD or USB image

From 11.04 onwards,when you boot the livecd and start installing it will give a option of upgrading to 11.04. it will automatically detect installed apps and install the updated version of your apps also. Assuming you're not dual booting.

[image: live CD : Allocate drive space]

### Upgrading using the command line:

- Run `do-release-upgrade` in a terminal

Answer (score 10):

If you're feeling adventurous, and have *already tried* one of the other methods listed here, and have had problem, or if you're just impatient, you can try this.

**If you want to try this, then read read the whole post first. If you don't understand part of it, then don't try  it.**

## The Brute Force Method

I have successfully used this to upgrade ubuntu installations over 4 major versions in one go, but **proceed at your own risk**. If you hit a snag, you might find it considerably harder to recover than with any of the other methods.

### Rewrite apt sources

First, simply replace all instances of your current version (`lucid`, `raring`, etc) in the apt software sources list with the new one, like this:

```
sudo sed -i 's/quantal/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

If you have some third party repositories that don't have newer versions, then this will cause errors on the next step, but you can safely ignore them. Software from those repositories may have problems due to updated dependencies, but more often than not they are fine if you're only upgrading one or two versions. You can deal with those errors by removing the relevant list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, or you can assume that the repository maintainer will eventually open a repository for the newer version, and just leave the files and ignore the warnings.

### Do the upgrade

Next step:

```
sudo apt-get update        # here's where you might get some errors you can ignore.
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # point of no return
```

On the second step, you'll probably have to accept some changes suggested that fix broken packages. Run an eye over the suggestions, and then accept the changes, if it doesn't look too drastic. You can fix most things in the next steps.

You will also have to answer questions about which version of package configs to use. Do as you see fit.

### Fixing breaks

You will undoubtedly get problems with package installs. To deal with these, first try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. If that gives you the same problem, then check the message (which will usually be a package file conflict), and manually remove the package giving you problems, with `sudo dpkg --force-depends -r <packagename>` (usually the older version of the two conflicting packages). Then run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again. Rinse and repeat until `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't do anything (all packages are upgraded).

### End game

**Important**: before you do anything else, make sure that all vital programs are installed. The easiest way to do this is to run something like `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` (or `kubuntu-desktop` or whatever version you're running). This will ensure that all the packages required by your desktop are installed, so you won't have trouble re-booting.

You can now run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get clean` to clean up old left packages.

If any packages were removed during the dist-upgrade step, then you can just re-install them as normal.

Answer (score 8):

“Never mess with your stable” is a lesson that I have learnt and is a mantra that I hold close to my heart. Especially when you have a good choice not to mess with your stable, you simply shouldn’t mess with it. Hence, I left my 10.04 unscathed and installed my 12.04 in another partition. Here is a screen shot of my hard disk :

[image]

I needed to have all the softwares that were there on 10.04 to be installed on my new 12.04.

1. First you have to know which all packages are installed in your 10.04. For that you can do

   sudo dpkg --get-selections "*" > pack_file

After running that, you will have the names of all the packages in 10.04 in the file called ‘pack_file’.

Transfer that file to 12.04 and run the following commands

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo dpkg --set-selections < pack_file`
- `sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade`

This will fetch all the packages as well as their dependencies and install it on your system. I had to download about 2GB of data but was at peace that my distro won’t get ruined.

It was 10.04 fro me but the approach would work on any version. Hence you can upgrade to the latest without "upgrade"ing. :)

Do refer to this : http://sosaysharis.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/upgrading-to-ubuntu-12-04-the-way-i-did-it/

Answer (score 6):

**Securely Upgrade 13.04 to 13.10 Using Command Prompt**

Since `13.10` has been released, many would like to know how to upgrade the previous version (`13.04`) of Ubuntu to Latest version `13.10`. Before upgrading to `13.10` it would be good to know the changes/support/compatibility.

So I suggestion to follow these steps in order to upgrade `13.10` effectively.

- First open `Software Sources` and be sure that possible changes has been set.

  - Run this command in terminal:

    ```
    sudo software-properties-gtk
    ```

    When `Software Sources` Window opens do these changes:
  - Under <kbd>Ubuntu Software</kbd> tab `tick` all four **Check Boxes**.
  - Under <kbd>Updates</kbd> tab `tick` first two **Check Boxes**, and set value of **Notify me of a new ubuntu release** to <kbd>For any new version</kbd>
  - Under <kbd>Other Software</kbd> tab `tick` first four **Check Boxes** and `untick/remove` remaining if someone don't like to upgrade the third party software that he/she installed by adding repositories. (recommend to remove).
- <kbd>Close</kbd> the window and execute following command to update repository:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Now it's time to check the compatibility/changes/support etc.. by `do-release-upgrade -d` option. <sub>To get more info run: `man do-release-upgrade`</sub> Type this command in terminal:

  ```
  do-release-upgrade -d
  ```

  It will download `Upgrade Tool Signature` of around 1 MB named something `saucy.tar.gz`. After that it will prompt password to extract it and finally check/fetch the packages in repository and after some time it will show the complete description of packages going to be upgraded, size downloaded and installed etc.. after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

  **13.04** can be upgraded at the same time to **13.10**, by press **Y** when prompt to install upgrades.

It is the easiest and most safest way to upgrade to **13.10**. Upgrades can be always be installed later if `aborted` before, by executing:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

<sub>To know more about dist-upgrade type : `man apt-get dist-upgrade`</sub>

Comment: This is just what I need to upgrade from 18.04 -> 18.10. Every other guide made no mention of the `-d` option. (I guess I could have read the help but hindsight is 20/20)

Answer (score 4):

Use Rinzwinds answer if you need a GUI-way to upgrade. If you need a CLI-way to upgrade, you should take a look at [this page](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2011/03/upgrading-ubuntu-with-do-release-upgrade/). The howto is from last year, but it should still be valid for 12.04. As soon as 12.04 will be released, this way should work.

And to answer your other question: 11.10 came AFTER 11.04. The first number is always the year (in this case: 11 means 2011), the second number ist the month or release (04 means April, 10 means October).

Last, but not least: As Rinzwind told you, you should wait until release and not upgrade to it while it's in beta. Unless you know what you are doing, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Execute these commands one by one :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also remove [ttf-mscorefonts-installer[image: Install ttf-mscorefonts-installer]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) before upgrading.

The reason is, that the upgrade process might get stuck on asking you to acceppt the EULA.

For workaround if the upgrade is already stuck, see this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/126082/55343

Answer (score 0):

For the recent Ubuntu releases, e.g. 12.04 onwards, once a new Ubuntu release is available, you will be prompted to upgrade. Once you click "upgrade" in the prompt, follow the instruction on the screen, you will be upgraded to the new release.

If there is no prompt, you can check the following.
Type the following command in terminal:

```
update-manager
```

The update manager window will appear and check for the updates. Install all the updates detected.

Click "Setting..." In the update manager, and click "update" tab of the window. For the question "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version", if you choose "For Long term supports version", the new Ubuntu upgrade may not be prompted as the new version of Ubuntu may not be the "Long Term Supports" one. If you choose "For any new version", the new Ubuntu upgrade prompt will most likely appear.

In https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases  you will find which version is Long-term supports (LTS) and which is not. Also, you will see each version's release date and life time. Quite useful information.

When the new Ubuntu version released, usually the upgrade prompt would not be appeared immediately. For when the new Ubuntu upgrade prompt will be available for your current Ubuntu version, you can check the Release Notes of the new version in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases