# ATI graphics drivers problem

Tags: drivers, ati

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 and in my graphic details it says that it is unknown. I tried to install the drivers from the AMD website and it installed perfectly, but when I reboot, after my login it only shows my desktop image and my resolution is changed.

So I uninstalled with the instructions from this website:
[How do I remove ATI/AMD Drivers downloaded from their site?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88573/how-do-i-remove-ati-amd-drivers-downloaded-from-their-site)

My computer is a Asus F5SL;

```
Dual Core 1.8Ghz;
ATI Radeon HD 3470;
3GB ram;
250GB HDD;
30GB partition for ubuntu;
Dual boot with Windows 7.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I had the same problem. So to tell you right away you cant fix this. You can only run it on default Ubuntu drivers. That's because AMD do not support 2xxx-4xxx graphic cards anymore. The only thing you can do is install proprietary legacy driver which downgrade your X Server(1.13) to 1.12. 
You can either buy a new graphic card 5xxx->, or wait for other solutions. Sorry to be a bearer of bad news. You can find some solutions but they all downgrade the X server...